# Leaving non-numeric values blank in ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, visualization

I'm trying to visualize some data using ListDensityPlot. Some of the data points may have bad values like `Indeterminate` which may come from taking `Log10` of a negative number. When drawing the figure, I wish to leave these places blank.

Here is a minimal example:

```
l = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 0.5}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, Indeterminate}};
ListDensityPlot[l, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

and the outcome is the left plot attached. Notice how the cell at `{2,2}` is extrapolated from the neighboring points.
What I want is to leave this cell blank (for example in `White`), so I tried

```
Clear[cf]
cf[x_] := ColorData["Rainbow"][x] /; NumericQ[x]
cf[x_] := White
ListDensityPlot[l, ColorFunction -> cf, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

but the result is the same (the mid panel).

What I want is something like the right panel, which I plotted using

```
ArrayPlot[{{0.5, Indeterminate}, {0, 1}}, ColorFunction -> cf]
```

Unfortunately `ArrayPlot` or `MatrixPlot` is not straightforwardly usable in my practical case because I have some non-uniform grid. Ultimately it is doable, perhaps by remeshing my data and so on. But before that I'm wondering is there anything can be done using `ListDensityPlot`?

In the past I have used the following way: (i) replace all the non-numeric values in `l` by `0.5*min` where `min` is the minimal value in `l[[;;,-1]]`, and then (ii) set `PlotRange->{0.9*min,All}` for `ListDensityPlot`. This works but becomes rather complicated when plotting several sets of data in a row which share the same color bar.

Any advice is welcome!

[image]

========= Edit on 16:37 May 18 =========

The `l` in my case is a scalar field on a spherical grid. Something like this:

```
grid = Table[{r*Sin[th], r*Cos[th]},
  {r, 1, 10, 0.1}, {th, 0, Pi, 0.1}] // Flatten[#, 1] &;
values = Log10@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, grid // Length];
l = Flatten /@ Transpose[{grid, values}];
```

Comment: what does `l` look like in _your practical case with non-uniform grid_?

Comment: @kglr hi, please see my edit in the post

Comment: thank you H. Zhou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try the following, you will see that the ColorFunction never sees "Indeterminate":

```
l = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 0.5}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, Indeterminate}};
Clear[cf]
cf[x_] := Print[x];

ListDensityPlot[l, InterpolationOrder -> 0, ColorFunction -> cf];
```

[image]

We can create a work-around by changing "Indeterminante" to some special number, e.g. 10^6  and then define the ColorFunction to give White for this number:

```
ll = l /. Indeterminate -> 10^6;
Clear[cf]
cf[x_] := If[x == 10^6, White, ColorData["Rainbow"][x]]

ListDensityPlot[ll, ColorFunction -> cf, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! The behavior of ``ColorFunction`` is quite interesting. Why this is so?

Comment: You will have to ask at: support@wolfram.com